# Loading a 64-bit dll with 64-bit JDK 1.7.0

Tags: java, dll

I'm using Java 1.7.0 on Windows 7 and trying to load a 64-bit dll located in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/app_name/`. I get the following error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\app_name\app.dll: %1
 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I copied the dll into a different directory (ie `C:\Temp`) and was able to load the dll just fine. I'm thinking this error is due to the fact that the dll sits under `Program Files (x86)`, and java is trying to load it as a 32-bit dll. Does the JVM make certain assumptions about dll's under `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`?

Comment: could be the spaces in the file path?

Comment: I don't think so, it seems to find the dll, its just trying to load it as a 32-bit dll rather than a 64-bit dll.

Comment: i just said that because i know sometimes languages complain about spaces in paths (a lot of linux stuff is like that) i do think it's fair to say that it makes the assumption that if it's in the x86 folder it's 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is not a question of the path. The only question goes to what version of the JavaVM you are using. If it's the 32bit version of Java, it will attempt to load any DLL as 32bit DLL, if it's the 64bit version of Java, it will attempt to load any DLL as 64bit DLL.

So, either
- You only have the 32bit Java installed on your system, and try to load a 64bit DLL; or
- You have both 32bit and 64bit Java installed, then you need to make sure that you use the 64bit version for your test.

The fact that you claim you have successfully used the DLL from a different folder suggests the latter, so make sure the java executable you use is the 64bit version.